# Which GCP Service to use for deploying background process

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

Problem Background:
I have a Dockerized app. App performs data processing in the background , uploads files to GCS, and exits.

This is not invoked by any HTTP or an event. I want to schedule this per week basis. I can use Google Cloud scheduler for this.

My question is which GCP service I should use to host the docker image?

**CloudRun** is not a preferred service as it is used mainly for web app/events / pub-sub etc.

**GKE**  IMO should not be used as my application is not a microservice and will not be invoked externally

**Google cloud function** is  not a suitable candidate as my application is heavy and time-consuming and might need powerful  CPU/GPU

The only option I could think of is using a Virtual Machine.

1. Use CloudBuild to Create a VM
2. Deploy a docker image on a VM
3. Run the Docker Image

Am I missing any GCP service which is more suitable for the background/stand-alone tasks?

Comment: 1) Edit your question and include a) Resources required: Memory, CPU, Storage, Execution runtime. b) How is the application launched/controlled? 2) Your application sounds like a candidate for Cloud Scheduler -> Cloud Run (which creates a VM). The VM destroys itself once execution is complete. Google Container OS VMs might be a good match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GKE and VM are your only options. I would prefer [GKE Autopilot](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/introducing-gke-autopilot) as it manages the infrastructure automatically and you only need to focus on your code. Also, you only have to pay for the time period while your pod is active - which is a big advantage for a background/CRON job when compared to a traditional VM.

Comment: I ended up using GKE much more suitable option.

Answer (score 1):

I have a side solution. Because you already use Cloud Build, use also Cloud build to run your container!

You can also add a [trigger with a scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/create-manual-triggers#scheduling_your_build).

Finally, set correctly the timeout and the disk size (if required) and enjoy